# И снова по поводу "просто"

Tags: пунктуация

Вот, скажем, такое предложение: "Просто(,) мне это не понятно". Тут "просто" — вроде как вводное слово. Значит, выделяется запятой, да?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такого вводного слова нет. Здесь "просто" выполняет служебную функцию, выступая в роли союза-частицы. Ср.: Но мне это не понятно. Ведь мне это не понятно. Запятую не ставьте.
***Просто мне это не понятно.***
Вероятно, вы знаете, что есть такая вводная конструкция "проще говоря". Она и в самом деле обособляется. В Вашем случае произошла трансформация этого выражения в частицу, не требующую выделения.

Answer (score 0):

Да, действительно, "просто" - это простая частица, относящаяся ко всему предложению в целом